# DataReader never enters Read()

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, prism, datareader

Using Prism 5 (if that matters), I'm trying to read a table into a class but when I run the program the SQLiteDataReader Read() is never executed (or so I think since its Breakpoint is never hit).

Within my solution I have a ModuleA with a ViewModel class with a method that will update Bindings in the View:

```
    public void ShowGeneral()
    {
        Personnel personnel = new Personnel();
        personnel = PersonnelDAL.GetPersonnelRecord(Human);
        pName = personnel.PersonName + " Esquire";
        pAge = personnel.PersonAge;
    }
```

PersonnelDAL.GetPersonnelRecord() is in a seperate Module. (This Module has References to SQLite).

```
public static Personnel GetPersonnelRecord(int id)
    {
        SQLiteConnection myDBconnection = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteDAL.dbConnectionString);
        Personnel personnel = new Personnel();

        try
        {
            myDBconnection.Open();
            string strQuery = "SELECT Person.*, Personnel.*," +
                " FROM Person, Personnel WHERE Person.PersonPersonnelID = Personnel.PersonnelID AND Person.PersonID = @PersonID";
            SQLiteCommand query = new SQLiteCommand(strQuery, myDBconnection);
            query.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@PersonID") { Value = id });
            // A Breakpoint set here is hit
            SQLiteDataReader myReader = query.ExecuteReader();

            // A Breakpoint set here is never hit
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                personnel.PersonID = myReader.GetInt32(0);
                personnel.PersonName = myReader.GetInt32(1);
                personnel.PersonAge = myReader.GetInt32(3);

                // etc
```

As a result the View displays no value for Age and only Esquire for name.

Why is myreader.Read() never executed?

Comment: Sorry, better description of Layout is:  DataLayer module with PersonnelDAL class with GetPersonnelRecord().  PersonnelDAL is used supposed to return Personnel object.

Comment: Are you swallowing exceptions?  Don't do that.  You have an extra comma in your sql before the FROM.  That would throw.

Comment: `Debugging actually works Wonders` try using it...

Comment: My intention is for public static Personnel GetPersonnelRecord(int id) to return type Personnel. Personnel is the class object name. I see why you're suggesting that though - Personnel should have a IPersonnel interface with a GetPersonnelRecord record in it instead of me using a seperare method.

Comment: MethodMan, sarc aside, you are correct. I'm self-teaching myself programming in my spare time, so I'll have to learn how to do that properly. There will be some dumb questions. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a bad comma in front of the FROM clause:

```
string strQuery = "SELECT Person.*, Personnel.*," +
            " FROM Person, Personnel WHERE ...";
```

You didn't post the entire code snippet, but I'm guessing you are swallowing the exception.  I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Lars, thank you. Yes, I had some other select statements in the Query hence the comma, but looks like therein is the problem. I thought maybe something was breaking due to something I was missing moving to Prism and MVVM.   RE exceptions I am catching SQLiteException but had the MessageBox.Show commented out since I can't now use it in Prism?